# RSA KEY Translating Hex to decimal

Tags: hex, key, rsa

Hi this is a very dumb question but how do I translate/interpret this kind of hex passage to string/decimal? do I just ignore the colon (:) and translate the hex passage byte by byte ? how do i get the value of the keys?

I tried to find hex translators online but they seem to not have colon appear anywhere so I was just wondering if that was not the right way to get the value

[rsa key example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3sQQ.png)

Comment: Your screenshot seems to be taken from OpenSSL (using the key info command). What is the purpose of your question? Usually you receive a public key for RSA encryption or signature verification. In most times it is wrapped in a PEM encoding that can be read by most programs.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your reply, I'm trying to derive the private key using RSA algorithm using values p, q and e, but im not sure how to write a program to interpret this ... do i just ignore the colons (:) and read them as hex ? for example 
p1 = 00:e1:b8:8c
i would just read it as
p1 = 00e1b88c 
in hex ?

Comment: @JaJa yes, that is the way to read the number. Make sure your programing/scripting language you use can handle such large numbers respectively use an appropriate data type for storing the large numbers.